# Prevent user from closing Google Chrome Application

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to know if there is any extension or maybe even another windows program altogether that can prevent the user from closing Google Chrome. This is for use inside my company where I would like to use Chrome's "Create Application" feature on our intranet webpage. I want the webpage to always be running. Preferably it could work by minimizing to system tray on clicking the close button. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a NoClose script from

http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#NoClose

Which allows you to set up and prevent programs closing, the AnyHotKey source is available as well so you should be able to customise it to your needs.